# audio codec kernel driver using alsa - capture path vs playback path

Tags: linux, audio, driver, embedded-linux, alsa

I'm using a custom board running **imx6q processor**, and a **tlv320aic3x audio codec**.
Everything works ok after some bring-up, but I'm trying to improve the audio driver: whether I'm doing playback or capture - both playback and capture related amplifiers are switched on.
This causes side effects like noise in speakers when I'm capturing audio, and wastes power.

To solve this, I'm trying to define the data paths correctly in the driver, but I keep failing.

I find it hard to find resources on-line explaining how to code an ALSA driver using the ALSA predefined macros that exists in the Kernel.
I've searched http://www.alsa-project.org/, linux docs, and few other sources...

And to my questions:

1. Is there any decent tutorial out there? I'm specifically interested in **DAPM** and usage of **control names**.
2. Is it possible to "re-program" all driver data paths from userspace?
3. Is DAPM sufficient for decent power management? Or should I use userspace to switch on/off power from unused paths in the codec between playbacks and captures?

Just to be clear: in user space using the standard driver, I am able to do playback, capture and control mixers, switches, etc... However I'm trying to achieve better automatic power management.

Thanks

Comment: Ask on the alsa-devel mailing list.

Comment: Thanks CL. Will try there as well.

Comment: Is there any audio codec driver that supports the voice IC Si3228x, I have searched alsa-devel and found nothing.